# How to get all private var names from a class in PHP?

Tags: php

`get_class_vars` gets all public vars, but I want to access private ones.

I am doing it from a parent class, trying to get the child class vars...

```
class A
{
    function getvars()
    {
        /* get private vars from child */
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    private $name;
}
```

Is there another method to do this?

Comment: Why make the variables `private` if you actually want to access them?

Comment: Related: [php reflection get properties without getting properties of base class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636999/php-reflection-get-properties-without-getting-properties-of-base-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using PHP's ReflectionClass.  In particular the `getProperties()` call.

Here is the PHP documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php

As sample would be:

```
class A
{
    function getvars()
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $vars = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);
        var_dump($vars);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    private $name;
}
```

Also note that you can change the filter on getProperties methods or omit it altogether (here I have shown the filter for private only).

Answer (score 5):

Use ReflectionClass to get them in an array. Then you can do whatever you want.
An example code to print their names on the screen.

```
class TestPrivate {
    public $var1;
    public $var2;
    public $var3;
    private $var4;
    private $var5;
    public $var6;

    public function getPrivateVars() {
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $vars = $reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE);

        foreach ($vars as $privateVar) {
            echo $privateVar->getName() . "<br />";
        }               
    }
}   


$instance = new TestPrivate();
$instance->getPrivateVars();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need, declare it as protected, this way you will be able to directly access properties in parent and extending classes.

Other way is to define protected/public getter/setter function in class introducing this property.

The hardest one is by using [`ReflectionObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) on `$this` in parent class to get list of private properties and [change their accessibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php)